# python parallell namspace issue

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a problem with the namespace in a simple Python Program: can anyone point me in the right direction

```
import numpy as np
import simple_sim
from IPython.parallel import Client

prescale_steps = np.linspace(0.5, 1.5, 101)
val = []

c = Client()
dview = c[:]
dview.execute('import simple_sim')
dview.execute('from numpy import *')
dview['prescale_steps'] = prescale_steps
dview['val'] = val

detuning_steps = np.linspace(-11,11,101)


def fid(det):
    for p in prescale_steps:
        tlist, ret =    simple_sim.simple_simulation(pulse_file='/home/andreas/Dropbox/puls25p8gn15map.mat', pulse_length=0.5, gamma=0, detuning=det, prescale=p)
        val.append(np.array([d,p,ret[-1]]))
    return val



lview = c.load_balanced_view()
res = lview.map(fid, detuning_steps)
a = res.get()
a = np.asarray(a)
```

always raises the Error: `global name 'simple_sim' is not defined`, although it should be defined shouldn't it?

Comment: What is the full traceback of the exception?

Comment: at line `dview.execute('import simple_sim')`
`NameError: global name 'simple_sim' is not defined`
four times for each kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `simple_sim` is in the path for your ipython engines, not just your ipython shell.

I.e. if `simple_sim.py` in `~/mydir/`, you need to run `ipcluster start --n=4` in `~/mydir/` or have `~/mydir` in your `$PYTHON_PATH` for the shell running `ipcluster`.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but it could be that simple_sim isin't in the site packages or in the same folder as dview. In the other words dview cant find your simple_sim module and therefore it produces error. However if that happens not to be case, I'm not sure what produces that error.